# Why is my Python list iteration not working correctly?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script where someone can type a username and the script will check if the directory exists, returning true or false as it goes through the list. Currently, the output is always "Not found"/false even though there should definitely be at least one true returned.

```
def scan():
    username = input("Type in the username here: ") 
    i = 0
    searchFor = folderList[i] + username
    listLength = len(folderList)
    while i < listLength:
        if os.path.isdir(searchFor) == True:
            print ("Folder found!")
            i += 1
        elif os.path.isdir(searchFor) == False:
            print ("Not found")
            i += 1
```

For reference, this code below which doesn't use a loop works fine, as if I type in the username and the correct index for the element of the directory that exists, it returns true, otherwise if I choose another index it's false as it should, so it's not an issue with the elements or folder permissions.

```
def test():
    username = input("Type in the username here: ") 
    i = int(input("Type list index number here: "))
    searchFor = folderList[i] + username

    if os.path.isdir(searchFor) == True:
        print("Folder found: " + searchFor)
    else:
        print("Not found!")
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: It looks like you think `searchFor = folderList[i] + username` is a dynamic variable that is re-calculated every time you ask for the value -- This is not the case. The value is set once and you never touch it again. Your first step in debugging should be printing out `searchFor` every iteration and you would immediately see that the value never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing an answer because the existing answers fail to address the problem, and I think they confuse things more than anything.

You currently have `searchFor` *outside* of the loop. As a result, it will be given a value *once* before the loop is entered, then its value is never changed. If you want its value to change, you must manually reassign it:

```
while i < listLength:
    searchFor = folderList[i] + username
```

Although, really, a `for` loop should be used here instead (but not as @Sai suggests):

```
for folder in folderList:
    searchFor = folder + username
```

You never use `i` for anything other than indexing `folderList`, so you should just iterate the `folderList` directly instead. Iterating a `range` is generally regarded as a code smell if you're just using the number to index a list.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the explanation, have changed it to a 'for' loop as recommended.

Comment: @Celias No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you

```
def scan():
    username = input("Type in the username here: ")
    is_exists = False
    for i in range(0,len(folderList)):
        searchFor = folderList[i] + username
        if os.path.isdir(searchFor):
            is_exists = True
            break

    if is_exists:
        print("Search is found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def scan():
username = input("Type in the username here: ") 
i = 0
listLength = len(folderList)
while i < listLength:
    searchFor = folderList[i] + username
    if os.path.isdir(searchFor) == True:
        print ("Folder found!")
        i += 1
    elif os.path.isdir(searchFor) == False:
        print ("Not found")
        i += 1
```